# Same hover and focus over two aligned tables from different divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, wicket

I have a scrollable table with last column fixed because that column contain action buttons.
On html code they looks like: two divs with a table in each div, first div contain main table and on second div I have a table with only one column on which I have added action buttons.  On tables I have a hover effect when cursor pass over tr td and on focus I applied a different background in order to highlights selected registration from table.
My problem is how can I have that hover and focus effect over booth tables in the same time when cursor pass over tr td because now they works independently on each table.

Please check my live example: [`http://mainpage.ueuo.com/`](http://mainpage.ueuo.com/)

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look here http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/5/

```
$(function(){
$('table tr td').click(function () { 
         var selected = $(this).parent(); 
         var index = selected.GetIndex();
            var parentOfRow = $(selected.parent()[0].tagName);

         //First remove the selectedRow class
        $(".selectedRow",parentOfRow).removeClass("selectedRow");
        parentOfRow.each(function(){
               $("tr:eq("+index +")",this).addClass("selectedRow");
         });
    });
$("tr").hover(function(){
     var row = $(this).GetIndex();
    $(".table").each(function(){          
          $("tr:eq("+row+")",this).addClass("hoverx");
    });
},function(){         
     var row = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    $(".table").each(function(){          
          $("tr:eq("+row+")",this).removeClass("hoverx");
    });
});
});

    jQuery.fn.GetIndex = function(){
        return $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    }
```

Comment: Is possible to have the same behavior from second div on first div? because now if I put cursor on first div will select only elements from first div table but if I go with cursor on second div is selecting booth div tr. Thank's.

Comment: I update the code this time it works fine. Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Do you think we can integrate on your function a focus? for example this: `function rowSelection() {
      $('table.grid tbody  tr  td').click(function () {
          var selected = $(this).parent();
          $('table.grid tbody  tr').each(function (index) {
              if ($(this).hasClass("selectedRow")) {
                  $(this).removeClass("selectedRow");} });
          if (!selected.hasClass('selectedRow')) {
              selected.addClass("selectedRow");
        }});
  }`

Comment: Thank you very much mate !!! You saved my day!!! I'll give you all points I can, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this two DIVs approach I would use this jQuery plugin that can fix columns and also rows:

http://fixedheadertable.com/

It would make your HTML more simple and standard.